# can't install third party .deb packages with the new ubuntu software app (ubuntu 16.04 )

Tags: software-center, deb, 16.04

The new Ubuntu Software Center - GNOME Software - fails to install any .deb package,  e.g., Steam, Google Chrome, etc.

When I double click the package the 'Ubuntu software' opens but when I press install it flashes a progress bar for a second then an icon appears in the dash saying "waiting to install"!

And nothing seems to happen at all!

P.S
1. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,  fresh installed (not upgraded) with Unity desktop.

2. GDebi successfully installs any .deb package

Comment: @muru: Right, but this question has a better title.

Comment: Do you face a similar bug ?

Comment: Not quite. I could install e.g. Google Chrome successfully, but I didn't download the .deb file manually first. OTOH I reported [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1563322).